# C# change value from datagridview and get the change on access database

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb

I don't have any idea how can I do this! 
I need to update database values when a value from field name is changed.

This is my method from DAL class:

```
public void UpdateClientName(Cliente c)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update Cliente set nome=@newName where nif=@nif;", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newName ", c.Nome); // parameter
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nif", c.NIF);

        con.CreateCommand(); 
        con.Open(); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        con.Close(); 

    }
```

This is my method from BLL class

```
 public void UpdateClientName(Cliente c)
    {
        DAL.DAL d = new DAL.DAL();
        d.UpdateClientName(c);
    }
```

Now I don't what to do! Because I don't know how to do and what is datagrid event for that ..

HELP PLEASE.

Comment: Datagrids have very rich binding capabilities. There is a lot of missing context to understand what all of your code does, but if you are trying to read data out of the grid and make an update then you are doing it wrong. [Check my blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/05/27/c-data-binding-example-with-adapters-and-datagridview/) with an example of using data adapters.

Comment: I 'll check that thanks!